# Are eigenfunctions of the Dirichlet problem for the Laplace equation uniformly bounded?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, eigenvector, laplace-equation

Let $Q\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a bounded domain with boundary $\partial Q\in C^\infty$ and $\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\ldots$ are eigenfunctions of the Dirichlet problem for the Laplace equation in $Q$ normed by condition $\|\varphi_n\|_{L_2(Q)}=1$. Does there exists a constant $M$ s.t. $|\varphi_n(x)|\le M$ for all $x\in Q$ and all $n\in \mathbb N$?

For $n=1$, say, segment $[0,\pi]$, $\varphi_n(x)=\sin nx$ and the stetement holds.

Comment: Isn't this wrong on the two-dimensional disk?

Comment: You might be interested in a paper of Toth and Zelditch with the title 'Riemannian manifolds with uniformly bounded eigenfunctions'. (There's a [copy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0002038.pdf) on the arXiv.)

Comment: A simpler explicit counterexample is the three-dimensional disk. For every $k$, the function $$ B_1(0) \ni x \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\pi} \frac{1}{|x|} \sin( k \pi |x|) $$ is a normalized Dirichlet eigenfunction of the Laplacian. Their values at $0$ grows linearly in $k$.